# Remove empty row after loop when moving to next worksheet while copying

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to combine several worksheets into one more pivot-friendly layout.
I copy/paste from the existing worksheets into a new worksheet and rearrange the data. This works fine, but when the loop moves on to the next worksheet it adds an empty row below the data.

I know that this is a minor inconvenience but i want to wrangle the data as little as possible before turning it into a pivot table.

My code so far:

```
Sub NewPivot()

Dim iRow As Long, iWorksheetIndex As Long, iNumberOfWorksheets As Long, iRowCounter As Long, iCol As Long, lastCol As Long

Dim wbkSource As Workbook
Dim wksSource As Worksheet
Dim wbkTarget As Workbook
Dim wksTarget As Worksheet
Dim strActiveWorkbook As String

Workbooks.Open ("C:\\Source.xlsm")

Set wbkSource = Workbooks("Sheets.xlsm")

iWorksheetIndex = 1
Set wksSource = wbkSource.Worksheets(iWorksheetIndex)

strActiveWorkbook = ThisWorkbook.Name

Set wbkTarget = Workbooks(strActiveWorkbook)
Set wksTarget = wbkTarget.Worksheets(1)


iNumberOfWorksheets = wbkSource.Application.Sheets.Count 'Count number of worksheets

iRowCounter = 0

For iWorksheetIndex = 1 To iNumberOfWorksheets

    lastCol = wbkSource.Worksheets(iWorksheetIndex).Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column

    For iCol = 0 To lastCol - 2 'last Column
    
        For iRow = 2 To 5

         If wbkSource.Worksheets(iWorksheetIndex).Cells(1, 2 + iCol) <> "Sum" Then 'don't copy if the header of the data is a sum

        'Copy data 01

            wbkSource.Worksheets(iWorksheetIndex).Cells(iRow, 2 + iCol).Copy
            wksTarget.Cells(iWorksheetIndex + iRowCounter, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                        
        'Copy data 02
                        
            wbkSource.Worksheets(iWorksheetIndex).Cells(1, 2 + iCol).Copy
            wksTarget.Cells(iWorksheetIndex + iRowCounter, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            
        'Copy data 03
            
            wbkSource.Worksheets(iWorksheetIndex).Cells(iRow, 1).Copy
            wksTarget.Cells(iWorksheetIndex + iRowCounter, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        
       
        Else
        
            Exit For
        
        End If
    
            iRowCounter = iRowCounter + 1

         Next iRow
    
    Next iCol

Next iWorksheetIndex


End Sub
```

EDIT: Spreadsheet layout:

Worksheet 1
Header1 | Header2
Data | Data
Data | Data
Data | Data

Worksheet 2
Header1 | Header2 | Header2
Data | Data | Data
Data | Data | Data
Data | Data | Data

Basically all worksheets contain a header and have varying numbers of columns but the same amount of rows (5)

Comment: Can you show an example of your source sheet?

Comment: I appended my question with the layout. I hope this helps @Zac

Comment: What's the **SUM** check for? If the header of data has **SUM**, don't copy that data set?

Comment: yes, exactly. I have sums accumlated from rows and i don't want to use them for the pivot.